# format an input field and print a round number

Tags: php, rounding

I'm complete new to PHP. I tried to make a simple calculation script. The problem I'm facing is that when someone inputs a number like "98,7" the number is rounded to "99" and the script prints out "99" instead of "100". So my questions is how to deal with this.

My script:

```
                if($omtrek >=53 && $omtrek <=57) $omtrek=55;
                elseif($omtrek >=58 && $omtrek <=62) $omtrek=60;
                elseif($omtrek >=63 && $omtrek <=67) $omtrek=65;
                elseif($omtrek >=68 && $omtrek <=72) $omtrek=70;
                elseif($omtrek >=73 && $omtrek <=77) $omtrek=75;
                elseif($omtrek >=78 && $omtrek <=82) $omtrek=80;
                elseif($omtrek >=83 && $omtrek <=87) $omtrek=85;
                elseif($omtrek >=88 && $omtrek <=92) $omtrek=90;
                elseif($omtrek >=93 && $omtrek <=97) $omtrek=95;
                elseif($omtrek >=98 && $omtrek <=102) $omtrek=100;
                elseif($omtrek >=103 && $omtrek <=107) $omtrek=105;
                elseif($omtrek >=108 && $omtrek <=112) $omtrek=110;
                elseif($omtrek >=113 && $omtrek <=117) $omtrek=115;
                elseif($omtrek >=118 && $omtrek <=122) $omtrek=120;
                elseif($omtrek >=123 && $omtrek <=127) $omtrek=125;
                elseif($omtrek >=128 && $omtrek <=132) $omtrek=130;
                elseif($omtrek >=133 && $omtrek <=137) $omtrek=135;
                elseif($omtrek >=138 && $omtrek <=142) $omtrek=140; 

                if ($omtrek < 53){
                    print 'Helaas'; 
                }
                elseif ($omtrek > 142){
                    print 'XXL'; 
                }
                elseif ($omtrek = round($omtrek)){
                    print("maat: " . $omtrek . "<br/>");
                }
```

Comment: Do you want to round up and round down?

Comment: Beware of using commas as decimals.  The string `97,7` (with a comma) is closer to 95 than it is to 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to round to the nearest "5" instead of "1". So, we can use that to greatly simplify what you're doing:

```
$omtrek = 5 * round($omtrek / 5);
```

That replaces your gigantic if statement tree. So your entire code boils down to:

```
if ($omtrek < 53){
    print 'Helaas'; 
} elseif ($omtrek > 142){
    print 'XXL'; 
} else {
    print "maat: " . (5 * round($omtrek / 5)) . "<br/>";
}
```

Additionally, as for your original point, that should be handled by your if structure, since `98.7` falls within one of the conditions.

Comment: this is a bad ass solution! Never thought of this, this way! Thanks for your help and comments.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having a long list of `if()` statements, why not just apply a little math?

```
$ cat om.php
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$omtrek = array( 52, 59, 61, 62, 63, 96.7, 98.7, 150);

foreach ($omtrek as $value) {
  if ($value < 53){
    $output='Helaas'; 
  } elseif ($value > 142){
    $output='XXL'; 
  } else {
    $output = round($value/5)*5;
  }
  printf("%6s => %s\n", $value, $output);
}

$ ./om.php
    52 => Helaas
    59 => 60
    61 => 60
    62 => 60
    63 => 65
  96.7 => 95
  98.7 => 100
   150 => XXL
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you are looking for is **ceil**

```
<?php
 $omtrek = 98.7;

 $omtrek=ceil($omtrek);

  if($omtrek >=53 && $omtrek <=57) $omtrek=55;
  elseif($omtrek >=58 && $omtrek <=62) $omtrek=60;
  ....
```

Then you can remove the round function as below...

```
if ($omtrek < 53){
    print 'Helaas';
}
elseif ($omtrek > 142){
     print 'XXL';
}
else{
    print("maat: " . $omtrek . "<br/>");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers provided by ghoti and ircmaxel are better than this.

Nevertheless, because you're new to PHP ... you may not know that if one `if()` evaluates true, the rest of them in an "else" chain won't even be considered.  So this would work:

```
            if ($omtrek < 53) $omtrek="Helaas";
            elseif ($omtrek <= 57) $omtrek=55;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 62) $omtrek=60;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 67) $omtrek=65;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 72) $omtrek=70;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 77) $omtrek=75;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 82) $omtrek=80;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 87) $omtrek=85;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 92) $omtrek=90;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 97) $omtrek=95;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 102) $omtrek=100;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 107) $omtrek=105;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 112) $omtrek=110;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 117) $omtrek=115;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 122) $omtrek=120;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 127) $omtrek=125;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 132) $omtrek=130;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 137) $omtrek=135;
            elseif ($omtrek <= 142) $omtrek=140;
            else $omtrek="XXL";

            print "maat: " . $omtrek . "<br/>";
```